# Laravel 5 jquery expandable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

**View**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
@foreach($faqs as $index => $faq)
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-{{ $index }}">{{ $faq->title }}</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-{{ $index }}" class="panel-collapse collapse out">
        <div class="panel-body">
            {!! $faq->description !!}
            @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
                <form action="{{ url('faqs', [$faq->id]) }}" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Delete"/>
                </form>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

**Example i copied**

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
           Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        ............................
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**This is when i expanded all three and collapsed then this happened**

[image: Pictrue one]

**This works well. but**

[image: Picture two]

> I think 1 way to solve this. when i expand some div other expanded
>   divs are will close. How do i do that? Or is there any way to solve
>   this problem?

Comment: Are you using `Bootstrap 3`? Could you show us the final HTML you get with PHP?

Comment: @azeós yes Bootstrap 3.7.7 . what do you mean? final html? you mean all of my HTML code of that page?

Comment: The pice of code generated inside `.panel-group`. According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion), `<a>` should have a `collapsed` class (if it doesn't start open).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the jQuery you are looking for:

```
jQuery('.accordian-toggle').click(function() {jQuery('.panel-collapse').hide();jQuery(this).parent('.panel-heading').next().show();}
```

Comment: `[ts] ')' expected`

Comment: jQuery('.accordian-toggle').click(function() {jQuery('.panel-collapse').hide();jQuery(this).parent('.panel-heading').next().show();});

Comment: Same error. i added `@section('javascript')
    @parent
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.accordian-toggle').click(function() {jQuery('.panel-collapse').hide();jQuery(this).parent('.panel-heading').next().show();});        
        });
    </script>
@stop`

Comment: can you please provide screenshot of error and code?

Comment: Sorry there is no error message. Just my view is broken. like that screenshot 1.

Comment: Is it still broken?

Comment: Yep. still broken i just don't know why. Now I'm trying to use https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_expanding_grid.asp